# .Net DataSet conncetion string update triggers change of query return types

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a .Net Framework 4.7.2 project with a `DataSet` for database communications. I have changed the connection string in the designer property window. The DataSet contains multiple tables/table adapters, and the table adapters occasionally contain queries. Some queries return a single value and have for example `integer?` as return type. As I changed the connection string, VS changed all of these return types to `object`. Can anybody assume the reason for this behavior?

Comment: *and the table adapters occasionally contain queries* - I'd like to know how you managed to create a tableadapter without a query.. and what it even does? Did you mean "the datatables occasionally have an associated tableadapter underneath" ?

Comment: *VS changed all of these return types to object. Can anybody assume the reason for this behavior?* - yes, it does it because it's a complete pain in the ass; you'll probably now have to trek through the XML and change all the ScalarCallRetVal attributes back to System.Int32. I recommend using source control (git), having the XSD committed to it, commit before you touch a dataset and then make your changes - Git will make it so much easier to undo when the designer pulls this crap. That's not to say I don't have a special love for it most of the time, but this part is detestable..

Comment: @CaiusJard My mistake, all tables have an associated adapter and I added occasionally queries besides the default Fill/ GetData queries which return one value. Yeah! You're so right, it's a pain in the ass. Maybe I should switch from creating everything via the VS GUI and create the DataSet via Code, or do you have a tip what would make this easier? Already versioned with git, so I can take that advantage. But the problem I see with this solution is that I must repeat this step every time VS regenerate the file "wrong". And therefore I would like to determine the source of this behavior.

Comment: Created via code? Eurgh.. Have you seen how much code it writes? I mean.. for sure you can take the good version of what it's written and preserve it.. If it's going to keep doing it to you, it might be better to just use the partial class feature (or subclass it) to provide your own method that calls the scalar, gets the wonky object and casts it. It's only the tail end of the generated method that ends up munged, returning object rather than doing the cast you want. I've never dug into it that deeply..

Comment: ..Though I'll admit I did once write a FileSystemWatcher based tool that watched for changes in the XSD and reverted any time it noticed `ScalarCallRetVal="System.SomethingDecent` -> `ScalarCallRetVal="System.Object`. It wasn't a difficult thing (a literal text edit, didn't parse and re-emit the xml), I was just so incensed at the time, by how stupid it was that some apparently inconsequential change would trigger it. It has other foibles but this one grates the most

Comment: When you are asking for a single piece of data, I expect the query is executed with ExecuteScalar. This method always returns an Object. Check for null then convert to the integer.

Comment: @Mary No, I can create queries, like I said, that return other types than Object. I create queries via the VS DataSet-Designer. In the background, code is generated that calls ExecuteScalar and casts the result to a suitable datatype. Like CaiusJard said, you can actually change the datatype inside the XML file.

Comment: Also consider posting your question on [developer community forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=61&entry=problem)